# vim on cygwin throws a error when I open a file

Tags: vim, cygwin

Every time I try to open a file in vim, I get this error:

```
330288 [main] vim 5824 fork: child 10000 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
```

I've seen this error plenty of times before but I can never figure out how to solve it.  I don't believe I have any BLODA.  Everything was working fine until about a week ago, and to my knowledge, nothing significant has changed in the past week.  I'm not sure what could have happened.

I tried reinstalling the vim package and rebasing, but with no luck.

When I open vim without opening a file, it works fine, but as soon as I try to write to a file, I get that same error.

Comment: have you tried a full rebase ? https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-02/msg00005.html. If it does not work a BLODA is the most likely cause.

Comment: I have run a full rebase, with no effect. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling vim, with no luck.  I'm not sure what BLODA could be causing this becauseNothing new has been installed on my machine since vim was working fine

Comment: so it turns out the problem is coming from a plugin somewhere.  I manually deleted my `~/.vim/bundle` directory and now it doesnt crash anymore.  But I've also lost all my plugins